# Random method using BufferedReader in ArrayList

Tags: java

/* In line 17 I want to get a random word using BufferedReader. I saw that many people use scanner like this: words.get(rand.nextInt) but I can't get around using BufferedReader with Random. I tried using readLine() but it is not possible because Random uses an int so I tried something like words.get(rand.Integer.ParseInt(words.size())) but this is also wrong. Excuse my english.*/

```
  1 import java.util.ArrayList;
  2 import java.util.List;
  3 import java.util.Random;
  4 import java.io.*;
  5 public class prueba {
  6         public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
  7                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
  8
  9         BufferedReader path = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("recursos/paraules.txt"));
 10         List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
 11         String currentLine = "";
 12         while((currentLine = path.readLine()) != null){
 13                 words.add(path.readLine());
 14         }
 15
 16         Random rand = new Random();
 17         String randWords = words.get(rand.readLine(words.size()));
 18         System.out.println(randWords);
 19    }
 20 }
```

Comment: Use `words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));`, just like you've seen. This has nothing to do with `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`, which are just used to fill the `words` list.

Comment: @Kayaman I've never used Scanner so I thought nextInt and nextLine were part of this class

Comment: They are, but there is `Random.nextInt()` and `Scanner.nextInt()`. One of those makes sense for the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()))` instead of `words.get(rand.readLine(words.size()))`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to implement this would be just:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("recursos/paraules.txt"));

    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println(lines.get(random.nextInt(lines.size())));
}
```